# Back pressure in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Supposed that I have 1 million lines of records in a database. Then I use Flowable (instead Observable) to read the records then write them into a file with slow encryption writing (writing is much slower than reading).

If I don't use ["reactive pull"](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure) during the writing, is it possible that my memory is populated with those 1 million records while the writing process is still half-way? In other words, is it possible to have out of memory exception?

If yes, is using "reactive pull" is the only way to prevent that exception, if I also don't want to use operators like throttling, etc.

Comment: It depends on what database that is and how you access it from Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how `Flowable` was created. For example if `Flowable` is created with `fromIterable` and the `Iterator` only requests new rows from result set when `next` is called then backpressure will be handled for you.

On the other hand if `Flowable` is created with `create` then behavior will depend on `BackpressureStrategy` that was supplied to `create`. If the strategy is `BUFFER` and `FlowableEmitter` just keeps pushing items then out of memory can occur. Ideally `Flowable` should be created with factory methods that handle backpressure naturally, if that is not possible then use other `BackpressureStrategy` like `DROP` or custom `onBackpressureXXX` operators. If everything else fails custom `Flowable` implementation can be created or found in some external library.

Comment: So, the flow of the data itself must be controllable by ourself for e.g. by pulling or the data is in the form of iterator. Also, doing `Flowable.create` is probably may have memory leak problem if using BUFFER.

Comment: yes, basically. not sure what you mean by "memory leak problem", all memory will be correctly released, there should be no leak.

Comment: Memory leak means OutOfMemoryException. Sorry for using a wrong term.